# Cronjob every minute

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a file in mysite.com/url1/url2/cronjob.php which has to be run every minute. I try every combination, but can't succeed. What should I run in command line? Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem? What combinations have you tried?

Comment: What's the problem? `1 * * * * /path/to/command` should do it.

Comment: What did you try. This will be easier for us to say why it is not working.

Comment: @alexn, wouldn't that cause it to run once an hour?

Comment: @alexn No. This would trigger the cron only when it's 1 minute after an hour. I.e. 1:01, 2:01 etc.

Comment: What path should I add? I think I have problem exactly here.

Comment: Yeah missed that one, it should be `* * * * *`. This can also be expressed as `*/1 * * * *`.

Comment: The best crontab tutorial I've ever seen: https://alvinalexander.com/linux/unix-linux-crontab-every-minute-hour-day-syntax

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In case you'd set it up in a crontab, this works:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/cron.php
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a difference between * and */1 ?

Comment: I prefer CLI mode than calling http URLS. anyways +1 because it works

Comment: @jasonbar The manual says *cron(8) examines cron entries once every minute.* So no. There's no difference.

Comment: @Ish So do I. Most "cronjobs" that are PHP based (like with Wordpress), don't work in CLI mode, though.

Comment: @Linus Kleen: It gives me an error: " Alert: Adding crontab has failed due to . Please delete it and add it again."

Comment: @hey `failed due to ...` I think something's missing?

Comment: @hey Are you using the command, @Ish suggested in his answer?

Comment: @Linus Kleen: no, I run your query

Comment: @hey Make sure, you *only* edit the crontab, using `crontab -e`. Also make sure, *each line* ends with a newline.

Comment: Don't edit the crontab file in windows, either - the windows newlines can screw it up an it will cause errors.  Edit directly on your system.

Comment: @Linus Kleen: where is crontab? I add this query here in command line:Period 

If Every Day The Hour 

Command *

Comment: @hey I am sorry. That makes no sense at all. Are we talking about a Unix shell?

Answer (score 2):

The PHP interpreter.

```
/[path-to-php]/php -f [your-php-script]
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps your shell

```
$ crontab -e


* * * * * php -f /path/to/cron.php
~
~
```

Answer (score 2):

I got confused for the first time where to add all of these and finally found.

Type the following in the linux/ubuntu terminal

```
 crontab -e
```

select an editor (sometime it asks for the editor) and this to run for every minute

```
*       *       *       *       *       /usr/bin/php path/to/cron.php &> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for help to make an UNIX cronjob?

If so, have you tried to edit /etc/crontab, and add

```
\1 * * * * user command
```

where user is either root or your name. Im not exactly sure how to access and URL, but a dirty way could involve downloading the link as a file, e.g. "wget http://url.com/page.php"

Comment: Ah thats true, my intention was to write \1, I think that is correct syntax? Asterix will do the same though. Sorry about that :)