# Cron time setup

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

Setting up cron is confusing, although I managed to set it to run every hour, but I can't quite figure how to change to run every 10 mins. This is the UI in admin panel:

[image]

Comment: this should be `*/10 * * * * /the/script.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what that specific UI interface allows...but if you can multi-select (hold down "ctrl" and click other minutes)...then just select 0,10,20,30,40,50

If you have access to actually edit the REAL crontab commands...the format is like this:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /path/to/command
```

Or...to simplify this, the "better" way is like so:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/command
```

Comment: WOW! I can infact select multiple values, its now `0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * *` :)

Answer (score 1):

The Cron should be like this:

*/10 * * * * /home/backup.sh

If you have access to your servers shell use the following command:

$ crontab -e

See:
[Cronjob every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901335/cronjob-every-minute)

Comment: Thats the problem, I can only select whole numbers from the dropdown, so can't select in minutes? :(