# How to create cron job using php script?

Tags: php, cron

I want to run my file's code every minute. Please help me.  I never used cron job so I am not able to do it.

Comment: What did you try? and besides, this is not a programming question

Comment: Do you have access to cpanel? You may find your answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cronjob every minute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901335/cronjob-every-minute)

Comment: [How do I set up a Cron job?](http://askubuntu.com/q/2368)

Comment: No, I have no access to Cpanel.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job Please visit on this link and do some search before asking any question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 crontab -e 
 */1 * * * * "job every minute"
```

Comment: My CMD does not support crontab command. I tried it many times.

Comment: what is your configuration or environment Lampp?

Comment: I have windows 2007. And I am using Xampp. But I want to use my cron job on my live project. But I dont have access of Cpanel.

Comment: and what is the configuration at live server?

Comment: I am using parallels Panel.

Comment: http://kb.xyzscripts.com/how-to-setup-the-scheduled-task-cronjob-in-plesk-control-panel/