# PHP data reload

Tags: php

Iam getting data from my api and adding it to og tags (name and image).
What I need is, update these og tags when name and image in api will change.

My code:

```
<?php

    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://radio.cloudradio.ml/api/nowplaying/1"));

    $site["activesite"] = "radio";
    $site["title"] = $json->now_playing->song->text;
    $site["img"] = $json->now_playing->song->art;
    $site["desc"] = "Rádio bota CloudRadio";
?>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your question is super unclear. Please give us a proper description about your app and more info about the issue.

Comment: I need to update my code every 1-2 seconds in php (for checking changes in api and updating og tags).

Comment: Okay, so what's stopping you from doing that?  This isn't a "hey, i need this, k thx" kind of place.  Do some research, make an attempt, and then if you're having trouble with something _specific_, we can go from there.

Comment: I tried to find it by myself.. but I cant find it. Iam searching one week for that. Thats why Iam here now.

Comment: Where is this code located? What are you doing with the `$site`-variable once it's populated? Please show us _all_ the relevant code, and again, give us more info.

Comment: ...and how is your code executed? Without knowing more, we can't really give you a proper solution without guessing.

Comment: $site varialbles are going to headtags.php to og tags.

```<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $site["title"]; ?>" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $site["desc"]; ?>" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $site["img"]; ?>" />```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **cron job** functionality. That means you can execute this php script that updates the variables can be executed for every minutes,hours or any unique time frequency. However, to reach this goal, storing data in database and than fetching to show in html is more proper. So update the database with php executed with cron job and then just fetch data from database to show in your html.

Check this article
[Cronjob every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901335/cronjob-every-minute)

Comment: I know about this, but I need to do it without database :/